# How to handle the change events in New UI (Experience space)

Tags: cme, javascript, sites-9.6

for CMS Custom functionalities,we can write custom Anguilla/JS code on relevant JS files for Classic UI. how to write same Custom Code logic in New UI?

for example:

```
 * @param {Tridion.Core.Event} event The event is the event fired from the <c>Tridion.Controls.Dropdown</c> control.
 */
Tridion.Cme.Views.InsertCpDialog.prototype.onTemplateChange = function InsertCpDialog$onTemplateChange()
{
    // existing code
    // new code write here
}
```

Comment: Just saying that there is an officially supported way to extend the old UI _without_ changing the original .js files…

Answer (score 3):

Extending the new UI (known as Experience Space) is not yet supported. This functionality is expected to arrive in the next release, Tridion 10.